# If scan.nextLine is a empty line then skip the empty line skip the following lines

Tags: java, scanning

Hello want to read a file with a scanner and save them in a ArrayList.
If the file has a empty file I want the scanner to skip the next line and also the following two lines without saving them in the ArrayList all the other lines should be saved in the arrayList.`
import java.io.File;

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Einlesen {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Subtitles Zeile für Zeile einlesen und in ArrayList wörter speichern
        ArrayList<String> wörter = new ArrayList<>();
        try (Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(
                new File("C:\\Users\\emely\\OneDrive - bwedu\\1Learn from the movies\\Pr_I_App\\Teil1.txt"))) {
            String s;

            while (scan1.hasNextLine()) {
                if (scan1.nextLine().equals("")) {
                    scan1.nextLine();
                    scan1.nextLine();
                } else {
                    s = scan1.nextLine();
                    System.out.println(s);

                    if ((s.equals(" ") == false)) {
                        wörter.add(s);
                    }

                }
            }
            scan1.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Einlesen hat nicht funktioniert.");
        }
    }

}`
```

Comment: what's wrong with your code?

Comment: Note that **every time** you call `scan1.nextLine()` it consumes a line.

Comment: You should store `scan1.nextLine()` in a `String` at the beginning of your loop and check against that, because of what @SotiriosDelimanolis said.